# Sort rows for duplicate ID numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to find ways to sort rows based on duplicate ID numbers per below but have been unsuccessful.

```
ID       SortOrder       PersonID
1        0               100
2        1               100
3        0               200
4        0               200
5        1               200
```

I am trying to sort the sortOrder column so the number 1 will display at the top for every PersonID.  So the end results are like below:

```
ID       SortOrder       PersonID
1        1               100
2        0               100
3        1               200
4        0               200
5        0               200
```

Any Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Is the ID column part of the table or not?

Comment: should the new ordering not change the order of the ID column as well ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm trying to keep the ID column within the same order.

Comment: @cs03295 That doesn't make sense - the ID field is, by its own definition, the identifying field for the record.  If you want something that retains the numerical order, you should look into using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` like this.

```
ORDER BY PersonID,CASE WHEN SortOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

You can change the `CASE` appropriately, if you want to change how following rows after `SortOrder = 1` should be ordered for the same `PersonID`.

Like `ORDER BY PersonID,CASE SortOrder WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END`

Answer (score 1):

**One other solution:**

```
select id,SortOrder,PersonId from 
(select id,SortOrder,PersonId,row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by SortOrder desc) as rn from table) A
order by A.rn asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments regarding wanting the ID value to stay in constant order, you're likely looking for something like this:

```
Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By PersonID Asc, SortOrder Desc) As ID,
        SortOrder,
        PersonID
From    YourTable
Order By PersonID Asc, SortOrder Desc
```

But, I'd caution against naming the `ROW_NUMBER` field ID, as it can be misleading since it's not actually the unique identifier for the stored record.